# Add marker to Google Map without knowing coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add a marker on the city on Google Map, but as I load the name of the city from DB, I do not know its coordinates. Is there any way to put a marker on the map without knowing exact coordinates of place we want to mark? Unfortunately, in [this examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) I do not see such options. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not search for the LatLong with their geocoding API and use that? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding